# How to migrate the CompositeUserType with parameters to Hibernate 6

Tags: hibernate, compositeusertype

I am migrating a custom type that implements `CompositeUserType` and `ParameterizedType` interfaces. This custom type serves for mapping, among other things, two arrays of numbers: `hardLevels` and `softLevels`. The arrays lengths are passed as parameters via the `@TydeDef` annotation.

However, the `@TypeDef` was abandoned in Hibernate 6 and replaced by `@CompositeType`, which does not accept any parameters.

The mapping looks as follows in Hibernate 5:

```
    @Entity
    @TypeDef(defaultForType = BendableScore.class, typeClass = BendableScoreHibernateType.class, parameters = {
            @Parameter(name = "hardLevelsSize", value = "3"), @Parameter(name = "softLevelsSize", value = "2") })
    class BendableScoreHibernateTypeTestJpaEntity {

        @Columns(columns = { @Column(name = "initScore"),
                @Column(name = "hard0Score"), @Column(name = "hard1Score"), @Column(name = "hard2Score"),
                @Column(name = "soft0Score"), @Column(name = "soft1Score") })
        protected BendableScore score;

    ....

    }
```

I tried implementing the new `CompositeUserType`, which works fine for a different class without the aforementioned arrays, but I fail to see how to migrate this type with the array sizes. I haven't found any example nor test showing similarly complex `CompositeUserType`.

Another concern is backward compatibility: the data persisted using this custom type with Hibernate 5 need to be correctly restored with Hibernate 6.

Comment: Same problem here. Instead of `@TypeDef` I use the `@Type` annotation and miss the possibility in the new `@CompositeType` annotation to set the parameters. Also within the documentation there is no explanation. This currently prevents a migration to Hibernate 6 (respectively Quarkus 3).

Answer (score 0):

One option to overcome this change the Hibernate team recommended to me is by using inheritance: implement the `CompositeUserType` as an abstract class and pass the parameters from its child classes via a constructor.
Of course, it does not keep full backward compatibility as the annotation-based approach for setting parameters is no longer supported. On the other hand, it offers the same level of flexibility.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would need to create a `CompositeUserType` for every constellation regarding the parameters. This is not flexible at all in my opinion. I have hundreds of properties that use a `CompositeUserType`, but nearly every usage has its own parameter (Hibernate 5). Do I need to write now hundreds of child classes?

Comment: That is my understanding. The child class provides the same information as the `@Parameter` annotation did. Feel free to contact the Hibernate team; perhaps they can come up with a better solution if more people ask for it.

Comment: I created an issue for this topic: [HHH-16597](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16597)